# Not able to upload photo using Content-Disposition in android

Tags: java, android, image-uploading, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload an image to server using Multipart/form-data, I have to send some text and an image in same call. when I an sending only raw data, it is working fine, but when I add "image upload part" it is not working. Below is my code.

```
 public String upLoadPostMethod(List<NameValuePair> params, boolean isUploadingPhoto) {
            NameValuePair nvp = params.get(1);
            String args = nvp.getValue();
            System.out.println(args);
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "********";
            HttpsURLConnection conn;
            String response = "";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize; 
            byte[] buffer; 
            int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024; 
            String mimeType = "image/jpeg";

            try {
                URL url = new URL(webServiceUrl);
                conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                //conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
                // Use a post method.
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie",
                        appStatus.getSharedStringValue(appStatus.AUTH_KEY));
                System.out.println(appStatus
                        .getSharedStringValue(appStatus.AUTH_KEY));
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

                DataOutputStream dos;
                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                // Send parameter #1
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"cmd\""
                        + lineEnd + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("tsql" + lineEnd);
                // Send parameter #2
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"args\""
                        + lineEnd + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(args + lineEnd);
                System.out.println("args======" + args);
                if(isUploadingPhoto){

                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";"
+"filename=\" 20130125_155208.jpg\"" +"Content-Type: "+mimeType +lineEnd+lineEnd);

                        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
+"/20130125_155208.jpg");

                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize); 
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize]; 

                    // read file and write it into form... 

                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 

                    while (bytesRead > 0) 
                    { 
                        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize); 
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 
                    } 

                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd); 
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd); 

                    fileInputStream.close(); 
                }else {
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd); 
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd); 
                }

                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

                Scanner inStream = new Scanner(conn.getInputStream());
                while (inStream.hasNextLine())
                    response += (inStream.nextLine());

                System.out.println(response);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return response;
        }
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to put `encType="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>` tag in form page:
See the sample code below, I hope it will help you:

As I am using Struts 1.3.8 and I have a user registration page in jsp where user have to upload an image along with some text information like Name, Address etc....

```
<html:form action="/register?s=r" method="Post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateFob(this)">

  <table width="65%" border="0" height="65%" bgcolor="beige">




.....
............
   </table>
```

Comment: My api is working properly, but there is some problem with the image upload part, which I am not able to figure out.

Comment: which type of problem ? Could you provide some more information? Or is it like that you are getting some exception or something? The code you gave above that is ok as I think.